# Composition and inheritance with generics in java - correct way to ensure types and avoid raw types

Tags: java, generics

Hello Stack Community,

Please guide me, what is the best way to enforce efficient, elegant generic typing while avoiding unchecked type assignment in following type hierarchy (I'm including as well in example my current typing solution, but I'v got a feeling that I failed massively somewhere...)

Interface for DAO operations (here generic type is obvious and reasonable solution I think):

```
interface DaoInterface<T> {
  T getData();
  T setData(T t);
}
```

Abstract Dao class for management (both class and interface shares same generic type):

```
abstract class DaoAbstractBaseClass<T> implements DaoInterface<T> {
  /* mostly data and configuration handling, thus needed */
  /* DAO operations ensured due to class generic parameter */
}
```

Actual implementation (Type used, to be able to infer and use types returned from Dao interface):

```
class ConcreteDaoImplementation extends DaoAbstractBaseClass<ConcreteType>
```

And now some abstract service class, that holds Dao instance and use it, field is mapped to lowest-level interface of Dao (since I'm only insterested in using it via interface operations):

```
abstract class SomeServiceClass<T> {
  private DaoInterface<T> dao;
}
```

And actual implementation of service with concrete type (`ConcreteType` in example):

```
class RealService extends SomeServiceClass<ConcreteType> {
  /* Dao is now ConcreteType*/
}
```

Actual DAO in real-life is provided by dependency injection from external world.

What I think is messed us is to grab generics to the most low-level implementation class just to parametrize top-level abstraction interface. Secondly, I think that construct `abstract class DaoAbstractBaseClass<T> implements DaoInterface<T>` as somehow naive to generify class just to ensure type of it's interface implementation... Can someone point out what can be enhanced or point out to some smart external materials? I'd be grateful!

## Edit

If someone found UML helpful, below is one, almost correct from formal point of view :)
[image: Class Diagram for this issue]

Comment: In `ConcreteDaoImplementation`, `T` is undefined.

Comment: "I used generics twice to ensure, that this particular abstract class will implement particular generic interface of same type" no idea what this means

Comment: @Michael, shadowing `T` was a copy-paste typo, there is generic return type, that's why extra set of `<>` left. I fixed it, sorry for confision

Comment: a "copy-paste typo"? I didn't know that was possible ;)

Comment: :D yayks just copied a bit too much and delete a bit too less...

Comment: I fixed misused generic `T` type on `ConcreteDaoImplementation`, now it shall be clear (at least I hope so)

Comment: Do you have methods in `ConcreteDaoImplementation` that are specific to the use of `ConcreteType` and different from other implementations of `DaoAbstractBaseClass`, or are you just using subclassing to avoid generics (pseudo-typedef antipattern)? If it's the former, I don't really see a problem with any of this.